# Django - WSGIHandler start_response and return response

Tags: python, django, django-views

**I edited my question, because I realized I was combining two concepts (WSGIHandler and Middleware)
which I shouldn't have combined in this question.**

I'm trying to get some basic understanding of what the `WSGIHandler` does.

**django.core.handlers.wsgi.py**

> class WSGIHandler(base.BaseHandler):
>       initLock = Lock()
>       request_class = WSGIRequest
>
> ```
> def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
>
>     #...
>
>     start_response(status, response_headers)
>     return response
> ```

An instance of `WSGIHandler` will be called with `environ` and `start_response` arguments.
`environ` will be used to create `request` object, which is an instance of `WSGIRequest`.

```
request = self.request_class(environ)
```

`WSGIHandler.get_response` will be used to create an `HttpResponse` object from `request`.

```
response = self.get_response(request)
```

**My questions:**
What does `start_response` do? By this time a `response` object has already been created. So what response does it start? Does it send some response somewhere? And where does it send the response sent by `return response` (i.e. what is it normally that calls it?)?

Comment: I edited the core of the question, because the original form combined two different concepts.

Answer (score 4):

When you write a web app, you need to provide a `callable` to the server which the server will call when a request arrives. This callable is responsible for generating a response and sending the response back to server. The server in turns sends this response back to the browser.

In case of django, that callable is `WSGIHandler`. Since it has a `__call__` defined, so this `__call__` will be called by the server.

The arguments sent to `__call__` are coming from server. `start_response` is also a callable which is implemented by the server. You do not need to worry about its implementation. So, `__call__` of `WSGIHandler` calls this callable `start_response`.

`start_response` internally creates the header which later has to be sent back to the browser. But it only sets some attribute on the server, it doesn't sent the response back to the browser. It doesn't send any response anywhere.

After calling `start_response`, wsgi handler returns the actual response in line `return response`. When this line is executed, the server checks if the response is proper and then based on the response either sends the cookies as set in `start_response` call or raises some exeption.

Check http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/ for more info.

Comment: `start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])` so this is just something I have to remember and not know why what and how it does whatever it does.